# Exce VBA how to generate a row count in that starts with specific row and stops at last row? Formula is flawed

Tags: excel, vba, count, row

So I have what might be a simple issue.  I have a worksheet where I'm just hoping to generate a row count starting with cell A4.  So A4 = 1, A5 = 2 , etc.  The problem is I'm not sure how to configure this with the following  goal:

1 - I'm hoping the count starts with cell A4 and ends the count at the final row with data.

The code I have below only works if I manually put A4 = 1, and also populates formulas past the last row unfortunately.

Please help if this is possible.

```
Sub V14()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DCT")

        .Cells(5, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF(DCT!B5="""","""",DCT!A4+1)"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What does *works if I manually put A4 = 1* mean?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - since the formula starts in `A5` (`Cells(5, 1)`), I believe OP means that `A4`'s value must be hard-coded separately as `1`.

Comment: Affirmative, I have to hardcode Cell A4 to 1, and then the formula picks up from there, where A5 = 2, A6 = 3, etc, but hoping to avoid the hardcoding of 1 in A4

Comment: @BigBen: Thanks, that clarified it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write Formula to Column Range

### The Code

```
Sub V14()
    
    Const wsName As String = "DCT"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const tgtRow As Long = 4        ' Target First Row Number
    Const tgtCol As String = "A"    ' Target Column String
    Const critCol As String = "B"   ' Criteria Column String
    
    ' Define worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Define Last Non-Empty Cell ('cel') in Criteria Column ('critCol').
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, critCol).End(xlUp)

    ' Define Target Column Range ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Cells(tgtRow, tgtCol).Resize(cel.Row - tgtRow + 1)
        
    ' Define Target Formula ('tgtFormula').
    Dim tgtFormula As String
    tgtFormula = "=IF('" & wsName & "'!" & critCol & tgtRow _
               & "="""","""",MAX('" & wsName & "'!" & tgtCol _
               & "$" & tgtRow - 1 & ":" & tgtCol & tgtRow - 1 & ")+1)"
    
    ' Write Target Formula to Target Range.
    rng.Formula = tgtFormula
    
    ' If you just want to keep the values:
    'rng.Value = rng.Value
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need an extra IF:

```
Sub V14()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DCT")
        
        .Cells(4, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF(DCT!B4="""","""",IF(A3="""",1,SUM(DCT!A3,1)))"
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: Hm, good point. I was assuming it was empty. Let's see if it's a problem for Amateurhour35. Ah, nevermind. I'll just change it. Thank you.

Comment: NVM, it doesn't work when I have a text header in cell A3.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim target As String  
Dim lastrow As Long
target = "A4"
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count 
'for example

Range(target) = "1"   
Range(target).Offset(1, 0) = "2"  
Range(Range(target),Range(target).Offset(1, 0)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(target & ":A" & lastrow + Range(target).Row - 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You only got to change the target cell, this does the rest.